# Fetching realtime data from mysql using php or network device using nodejs

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I am working on a project that displays realtime data sent by network devices every 1 seconds.There may me multiple devices to connect every second.Currently we are using PHP for this project. Since PHP works in blocking mode, it doesn't get data from all devices in a second Like if we have 10 devices to connect then it may take 10 seconds for PHP to get data from all devices (if it takes 1 second for each device).So we are planning to move to nodejs for data reading from devices and displaying it to user since it works in non blocking mode and it gets data from all devices at once.

We also have another option for this. That is read the real time data from devices and save it to mysql using PHP by making crun job every second and reading from mysql every 1 second. This also works faster.
Which one do I prefer. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: If you already have it built out in PHP, use AJAX to retrieve new results which you store in a database every second. You could do a CRON job I suppose, but that seems silly. Either way would be easier than moving it all to Node.js, though.

Comment: Node.js is going to work faster, and you can split out the actual code doing the work from the database management and sockets management. Using the cron is liable to break and is more of a 'hack' than doing it properly.